# Calculate percentage change between 2 columns

Tags: database-design, percentage, postgresql

I have a table that has 2 columns that list the amount of a specific item per release of our product. I need to calculate the percentage increase between the two columns and append it to a new column in the table, however I have not found any documentation that relates to this? I'm using Postgres 9.0, and I need to examine the percentage increase between the two columns as a part of the QC process to ensure there is no missing/wrong data between releases.

Here's the table definition:

```
oid oid[] NOT NULL,
"State" character varying(2)[] NOT NULL,
release_1121 numeric NOT NULL,
release_1122 numeric NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT oid PRIMARY KEY (oid)
```

I'd like to add a percentage increase column and populate it with the correct percentages.

Comment: 1121, 1122 — those are fields names or values? Please, post a complete table definition here. And show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Seems like there should be a `release` table with *one* amount per release and a view / function computing the change between all / selected releases. **Not** a table for the delta between releases. Also, please mention your version of Postgres and the intended purpose of the calculation (to better understand what you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, that adding percentage increase column is a one time operations, that can be done like this ([details in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE target ADD pct float;
```

And then you can update the table, populating it with new values:

```
UPDATE target SET pct = (after::float - before::float) / before::float;
```

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this is what you actually need:

Table should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE release (
release_id integer PRIMARY KEY,    -- pk is NOT NULL automatically
-- state varchar(2)[] NOT NULL,    -- ??
amount numeric NOT NULL
);
```

Test data:

```
INSERT INTO release VALUES (release_id, amount)
  (1121, 25)
, (1122, 30)
, (1123, 90)
, (1124, 10);
```

Query:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
         , lag(amount) OVER (ORDER BY release_id) as last_amount
    FROM   release
    )
SELECT release_id, amount
     , (amount - last_amount) AS abs_change
     , round((100 * (amount - last_amount)) / last_amount, 2) AS percent_change
FROM   x
ORDER  BY release_id;
```

[CTE (`WITH` clause)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and window function [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) require PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.
Result:

```
release_id | amount | abs_change | percent_change
-----------+--------+------------+---------------
1121       | 25     | <NULL>     | <NULL>
1122       | 30     | 5          |  20.00
1123       | 90     | 60         | 200.00
1124       | 10     | -80        | -88.89
```

- Don't use `oid` as primary key! That is bad practice. In PostgreSQL 9.0 [`WITHOUT OIDS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) is the default. [Read more here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS)
- Don't use [mixed case identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) like `"State"` if you can avoid it. See:

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: This is just *exactly* what I was thinking of suggesting before I got to your answer! No redundant storage of amounts, so if one amount is found to be incorrect, you fix that one amount and you're done; there is no need to hunt down redundant copies or recalculate dependent values.

Comment: @kgrittn: Same idea, probably because it is the obvious path to avoid redundant storage. :)